# Output data from mysql to array json driving me crazy

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

im trying to pull out a menu in this json format :
check the output : http://www.alacarta.do/iphone/webservices/restaurants_menu2.php?r=415

The thing is that iterating of the Category plates, it duplicates the plates and then add the corresponding correct ones in each Category. all the time. check the output in the link. first category is TO SHARE. and the plates are ok, but the second category FRIES BAR, will throw again the plates from TO SHARE and then the correct plates in its category

```
<?

$where = empty($_GET['r'])? NULL : 'id = '. intval($_GET['r']); 
$restaurant = $cmp->empresas($where,"nombre ASC")->fetch();
$json = array();
$arraynombre = array();

        while($orden = $cmp->platos_tipos_orden("id_empresa = {$restaurant->id}","orden ASC")->foreachrow()):

        $tipo = $cmp->platos_tipos("id = {$orden->id_tipo}")->fetch();

            while($menu = $cmp->platos_menu("id_tipo = {$orden->id_tipo} AND id_empresa = {$orden->id_empresa}")->foreachrow()):            
            $p = $cmp->platos_lista("id = {$menu->id_plato}")->fetch();
            $pnombre = $p->nombre; 
            $pid = $p->id;
            $pprecio = $p->precio;
            $arraynombre1 = array('plato_id'=>$pid,'plato_nombre'=>$pnombre,'precio'=>$pprecio);

                if (in_array($arraynombre1['plato_id'], $arraynombre['plato_id'])) continue;

            $arraynombre[] = $arraynombre1;

endwhile;


$jsondata = array('tipo'=> utf8_decode($tipo->nombre),'platos' => $arraynombre);
$json[] = $jsondata;             
endwhile;


      echo json_encode( array("menu"=>$json));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is probably this line -

```
$arraynombre[] = $arraynombre1;
```

as you continually add to the array, not overwrite the previous loops values.

Try adding a key to it that is unique to each loop, ie. `$orden->id_tipo` -

```
$arraynombre[$orden->id_tipo][] = $arraynombre1;
```

Then you would also need to change

```
$jsondata = array('tipo'=> utf8_decode($tipo->nombre),'platos' => $arraynombre);
```

to

```
$jsondata = array('tipo'=> utf8_decode($tipo->nombre),'platos' => $arraynombre[$orden->id_tipo]);
```

---

note- it is hard to follow all your code logic, so `[$orden->id_tipo]` might need to be `[$orden->id_empresa]` or could be a similar counter var `[$x]` that you increase on each loop.